# Significant digits with IEEE 754 float

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

The Wiki [Double-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) says:

> This gives 15–17 significant decimal digits precision. If a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double precision representation and then converted back to a string with the same number of significant digits, then the final string should match the original. If an IEEE 754 double precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 17 significant digits and then converted back to double, then the final number must match the original.

Can anybody give me some example to show how the conversion match the original, and in which cases it doesn't?

Comment: Err, a decimal string with > 15 significant digits as source, or a decimal string with < 17 significant digits as target?

Answer (score 0):

With 15 significant digits, from string to double and back...

```
std::istringstream iss("0.123456789012345");
double d;
iss >> d;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(15) << d;
std::cout << "should be 0.123456789012345 but might have changed: " << oss.str() << '\n';
```

Note: for some 15 significant-digit initial input strings, the above code *may* output a different final string.  Here's a program that attempts to find a 15 digit string input for which the value isn't preserved by conversion to and from a `double`, but [all values pass for GCC on coliru.stackedcrooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2631c9ab60cd6a23).  That doesn't mean it wouldn't fail for some other values in a different range.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int results = 0;

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i <= 999999999999999; ++i)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "0." << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(15) << i;
        std::istringstream iss(oss.str());
        double d;
        iss >> d;
        std::ostringstream oss2;
        oss2 << std::fixed << std::setprecision(15) << d;
        if (oss.str() != oss2.str())
        {
            std::cout << "from " << oss.str() << '\n' << "  to " << oss2.str() << '\n';
            if (++results > 50) exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

With 17 significant digits, from double to string and back...

```
double d = 0.12345678901234567;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(17) << d;
std::istringstream iss(oss.str());
double d2;
iss >> d2;
std::cout << "d must equal d2: " << std::boolalpha << d == d2 << '\n';
```

This should *never* fail to recover an identical `double` value from the textual representation.

Comment: As Wiki says, a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits should match the original. So in your first example, why do you think the final result might have changed?

Comment: @cssmlulu: because of the seemingly (to me at the time) pointed use of *should* vs. *must* - but then I may have been reading too much into it.  I thought that was quoting from something like the C or C++ Standard (maybe my mind playing tricks, but it seemed vaguely familiar). I haven't checked the maths to see whether there's any reason it can't always work, nor yet tried to see if that stipulation mirrors a Standard.